# Detect Apple Pencil 2 double tap in browser

Tags: javascript, ios, browser, apple-pencil

Apple Pencil 2 now [supports a double-tap](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/pencil_interactions/handling_double_taps_from_apple_pencil) near the tip of the pencil to perform auxiliary functions in supported apps.

Is there any way to detect this double-tap in a browser?

It doesn't seem to trigger any of the usual event suspects (`click`, `pointerdown`, `mousedown`) etc...

Comment: The first gen pencil triggered a touchstart event upon touching. Might be worth a shot

Comment: @Kilian The double tap is by your finger on the pencil itself. Not the pencil to the screen. If I'm not mistaken Apple Pencil 2 just introduced a sensor on the pencil itself. Apple Pencil 1 doesn't have it. In any case though I've tried `touchstart` and it's not fired.